# UITextView says it's empty when it's not

Tags: ios, uitextview, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to get the text contents of a simple `UITextView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`.  Basically, when the user shares a certain cell, I want to grab what's written in that cell to use in the `ActivityViewController`.

The thing is, it's saying it's blank.  It's clearly not blank: I'm looking right at it when I click Share, and it's got text in it.  (The text is a reverse-lookup address of the location at which a photo was taken.)

My very inexperienced eye thinks that the problem is that the TextView is being populated by a block.  I don't know why that would be a problem, but it seems to jump out at me.

Below are the methods for setting up the cell (and thus setting the text of the TextView), followed by the Share method that's supposed to grab it:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ALAsset *asset = [_photosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

    [cell.labelMain setText:[assetRep filename]];

    CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;
                       }
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                       NSArray *addressArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]];
                       [cell.textViewDescription setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", [addressArray objectAtIndex:0], [addressArray objectAtIndex:1], [addressArray objectAtIndex:2]]];
                   }];

    return cell;
}
```

That all seems to work perfectly.  But then in the Share method below, `locationName` is inexplicably blank:

```
-(void)sharePic {
    PhotoCell *currentCell = (PhotoCell*)[self collectionView:_collectionViewMain cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:_selectedIndex inSection:0]];

    NSString *locationName = [[currentCell textViewDescription] text];
    NSArray *arrayOfActivityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:locationName, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                            initWithActivityItems:arrayOfActivityItems applicationActivities:nil];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Am I correct in thinking that the block is what's causing the string `locationName` to be empty in the Share method?  (It's properly initialized, just an empty string).  And if so, is there a way around it?  Or if not, any idea why `locationName` comes out as blank, even though the `textViewDescription` has text in it?

All I want is to get the text in that field...

Comment: If I remember well, you CoreLocation block is asynchronous, when you `sharePic`, is it already finished? Did you check if *currentCell* was not *nil*?

Comment: Don't get the text back from the cell. The text should be in your data model and you should get it from there...

Comment: @Larme currentCell isn't nil, because I can pull other things from it, such as the `labelMain` that gets set earlier, without any problem.

Comment: @Wain Good suggestion, and I'll look into it, but the question remains.  If you can't pull text from fields filled by blocks I'd like to know why, rather than just avoiding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get the text back from the cell. The text should be in your data model and you should get it from there...

That said, your problem is nothing to do with blocks (though asynchronous operations could cause you issues sometimes). The problem is that you are creating a new cell rather than getting the existing cell. Instead of:

```
PhotoCell *currentCell = (PhotoCell*)[self collectionView:_collectionViewMain cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:_selectedIndex inSection:0]];
```

you should have:

```
PhotoCell *currentCell = (PhotoCell*)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:_selectedIndex inSection:0]];
```

Comment: Aha!  Thanks!  And yeah, I'm looking into a better solution, but thanks for the answer!